# Specify template parameters at runtime

Tags: c++, templates

Consider the following template class

```
class MyClassInterface {
public:
  virtual double foo(double) = 0;
}

class MyClass<int P1, int P2, int P3>
: public MyClassInterface {
public:
  double foo(double a) {
    // complex computation dependent on P1, P2, P3
  }
  // more methods and fields (dependent on P1, P2, P3)
}
```

The template parameters `P1`, `P2`, `P3` are in a restricted range like from `0` to some fixed value `n` fixed at compile time.

Now I would like to build a "factory" method like

```
MyClassInterface* Factor(int p1, int p2, int p3) {
  return new MyClass<p1,p2,p3>(); // <- how to do this?
}
```

The question would be how to achieve the construction of the template class when template parameters are only known at runtime. And would the same be possible with template parameters having a very large domain (like a double)? Please consider also, if the possible solution is extendable to using more template parameters.

Comment: I'd really like to know the reason beyond that question. Could you explain us what you are trying to achieve by using this odd construct ?

Comment: There is a huge algorithm which can be parameterized using template integer parameters. Dependent on the parameters, the compile generates some highly optimized code. Now I want to be able to use those different "versions" from outside without caring about their implementation and by specifiying parameters at runtime in a user-supervised manner.
Despite this application, this was also meant to be a theoretical question out of pure curiosity.

Comment: Note that due to the instantiation of a possibly large number of specializations, the resulting executable huge size may technically go against your optimizations performancewise. Large code often means slow code, especially in the presence of irregular branching patterns. (as always, profile to know what's going on)

Comment: Related: [Idiom for simulating run-time numeric template parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38914655/idiom-for-simulating-run-time-numeric-template-parameters).

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Here's what you can do:

```
MyClassInterface* Factor(int p1, int p2, int p3) {
  if (p1 == 0 && p2 == 0 && p3 == 0)
    return new MyClass<0,0,0>();
  if (p1 == 0 && p2 == 0 && p3 == 1)
    return new MyClass<0,0,1>();
  etc;
}
```

Note that this does not even remotely scale to floating point values. It scales only to a known list of discrete values.

---

I've also used this bit of code before to do some template automatic generation:

```
#include <boost/preprocessor.hpp>

#define RANGE ((0)(1)(2)(3)(4)(5)(6)(7)(8)(9)(10)(11)(12))
#define MACRO(r, p) \
    if (BOOST_PP_SEQ_ELEM(0, p) == var1 && BOOST_PP_SEQ_ELEM(1, p) == var2 && BOOST_PP_SEQ_ELEM(2, p) == var3 && BOOST_PP_SEQ_ELEM(3, p) == var4) \
        actual_foo = foo<BOOST_PP_TUPLE_REM_CTOR(4, BOOST_PP_SEQ_TO_TUPLE(p))>;
BOOST_PP_SEQ_FOR_EACH_PRODUCT(MACRO, RANGE RANGE RANGE RANGE)
#undef MACRO
#undef RANGE
```

The compiler produces output that looks like this:

```
if (0 == var1 && 0 == var2 && 0 == var3 && 0 == var4) actual_foo = foo<0, 0, 0, 0>;
if (0 == var1 && 0 == var2 && 0 == var3 && 1 == var4) actual_foo = foo<0, 0, 0, 1>;
if (0 == var1 && 0 == var2 && 0 == var3 && 2 == var4) actual_foo = foo<0, 0, 0, 2>;
if (0 == var1 && 0 == var2 && 0 == var3 && 3 == var4) actual_foo = foo<0, 0, 0, 3>;
if (0 == var1 && 0 == var2 && 0 == var3 && 4 == var4) actual_foo = foo<0, 0, 0, 4>; 
if (0 == var1 && 0 == var2 && 0 == var3 && 5 == var4) actual_foo = foo<0, 0, 0, 5>;
if (0 == var1 && 0 == var2 && 0 == var3 && 6 == var4) actual_foo = foo<0, 0, 0, 6>;
if (0 == var1 && 0 == var2 && 0 == var3 && 7 == var4) actual_foo = foo<0, 0, 0, 7>;
if (0 == var1 && 0 == var2 && 0 == var3 && 8 == var4) actual_foo = foo<0, 0, 0, 8>;
etc...
```

---

Also, please note that with this method, with 4 variables, each ranging over 13 values, You  would cause the compiler to instantiate 28561 copies of this function. If your n was 50, and you still had 4 options, you would have 6250000 functions instantiated. This can make for a SLOW compile.

Comment: 'This can make for a SLOW compile' - Not to mention a preprocessed size approaching half a gigabyte and a massive resulting executable size if you ever found a compiler that could cope with that.

Comment: @Joe: Absolutely. I've used this for a set of bools that I wanted to try templating out. I think the most I ever did was < 100 generated instantiations.

Comment: Why didn't you use `BOOST_PP_SEQ_ENUM_PARAMS` instead of converting to tuple and removing the constructor ? Is there an efficiency reason ?

Comment: @Matthieu: The efficiency of the macro generation isn't really an issue. I never used this code for more than a day, so it was just hacked together. The only other comment would be that I was using Boost 1.33.1 which may or may not support some additional macro calls.

Comment: @sharth What makes you think that floating point values aren't discrete? There are even less float values than there are int values, because NaN and co. have some duplicate representations.

Comment: @Fred: I'm more referring to the fact that if your range is [0, 10], it's a lot easier to do that if you are using ints, rather than floats. It's not that there are not a finite number of floats in that range, it's that there are far too many.

Comment: A slow compile, **and** a possibly slow runtime due to code size and instruction cache misses, defeating the point of doing compile-time micro optimization in the first place. This seems important enough to be noted.

Answer (score 16):

If macros aren't your thing then you can also generate the if-then-else's using templates:

```
#include <stdexcept>
#include <iostream>

const unsigned int END_VAL = 10;

class MyClassInterface
{
public:
    virtual double foo (double) = 0;
};

template<int P1, int P2, int P3>
class MyClass : public MyClassInterface
{
public:
    double foo (double a)
    {
        return P1 * 100 + P2 * 10 + P3 + a;
    }
};

struct ThrowError
{
    static inline MyClassInterface* create (int c1, int c2, int c3)
    {
        throw std::runtime_error ("Could not create MyClass");
    }
};

template<int DEPTH = 0, int N1 = 0, int N2 = 0, int N3 = 0>
struct Factory : ThrowError {};

template<int N2, int N3>
struct Factory<0, END_VAL, N2, N3> : ThrowError {};

template<int N1, int N3>
struct Factory<1, N1, END_VAL, N3> : ThrowError {};

template<int N1, int N2>
struct Factory<2, N1, N2, END_VAL> : ThrowError {};

template<int N1, int N2, int N3>
struct Factory<0, N1, N2, N3>
{
    static inline MyClassInterface* create (int c1, int c2, int c3)
    {
        if (c1 == N1)
            return Factory<1, N1, 0, 0>::create (c1, c2, c3);
        else
            return Factory<0, N1 + 1, N2, N3>::create (c1, c2, c3);
    }
};

template<int N1, int N2, int N3>
struct Factory<1, N1, N2, N3>
{
    static inline MyClassInterface* create (int c1, int c2, int c3)
    {
        if (c2 == N2)
            return Factory<2, N1, N2, 0>::create (c1, c2, c3);
        else
            return Factory<1, N1, N2 + 1, N3>::create (c1, c2, c3);
    }
};

template<int N1, int N2, int N3>
struct Factory<2, N1, N2, N3>
{
    static inline MyClassInterface* create (int c1, int c2, int c3)
    {
        if (c3 == N3)
            return new MyClass<N1, N2, N3> ();
        else
            return Factory<2, N1, N2, N3 + 1>::create (c1, c2, c3);
    }
};

MyClassInterface* factory (int c1, int c2, int c3)
{
    return Factory<>::create (c1, c2, c3);
}
```

Since the tests are nested it should be more efficient than sharth's macro solution.

You can extend it to more parameters by adding more depth cases.

Answer (score 10):

Thats not posible, templates are instantiated at compile time.
By the time you have an executable you only have classes(particular instantiations of those templates), no templates any more.

If you don't know values at compile time you can't have templates for those.

Comment: This is not true. For integer parameters with a small domain, one can use switch/if statements, as indicated in the post by sharth.

Comment: There is no way of `achieve the construction of the template class when template parameters are only known at runtime` without constructing all the possible cases and doing runtime switching.

Comment: And the question was how to for example do this recursive switching (without writing it out in code by hand).

Answer (score 3):

I don't know if this is applicable to your current problem, but it would appear that C++11
`constexpr` may be what you are looking for - `constexpr` functions may be called during runtime and at the same time may be executed at compile time.

The use of `constexpr` also has the added benefits of being far "cleaner" looking than using TMP, working with any runtime values (not just integral values) whilst retaining most of TMP's benefits such as memoization and compile time execution, although this is somewhat given to the compiler's decision. In fact, `constexpr` is usually much faster than a TMP equivalent version.

Note also that in general the use of templates during runtime would undermine one of template's greatest features - The fact that they are handled during compile time and pretty much disappear during runtime.

Comment: Example please?

Answer (score 2):

It is technically *possible** - but it's not practical and it's almost certainly the wrong way to approach the problem.

Is there some reason why P1, P2 and P3 can't be regular integer variables?

---

*You could embed a C++ compiler and a copy of your source, then compile a dynamic library or shared object that implements your factory function for a given set of P1,P2,P3 - but do you really want to do that? IMO, that's an absolutely crazy thing to be doing.

Answer (score 1):

You can't. template are compile time only.

You can build at compile time all the possible templates values you want, and choose one of them in run time.

Answer (score 0):

way too late, i know, but what about this:

```
// MSVC++ 2010 SP1 x86
// boost 1.53

#include <tuple>
#include <memory>
// test
#include <iostream>

#include <boost/assert.hpp>
#include <boost/static_assert.hpp>
#include <boost/mpl/size.hpp>
#include <boost/mpl/vector.hpp>
#include <boost/mpl/push_back.hpp>
#include <boost/mpl/pair.hpp>
#include <boost/mpl/begin.hpp>
#include <boost/mpl/deref.hpp>
#include <boost/mpl/int.hpp>
#include <boost/mpl/placeholders.hpp>
#include <boost/mpl/unpack_args.hpp>
#include <boost/mpl/apply.hpp>
// test
#include <boost/range/algorithm/for_each.hpp>

/*! \internal
 */
namespace detail
{
/*! \internal
 */
namespace runtime_template
{

/*! \internal
    fwd
 */
template <
    typename Template
    , typename Types
    , typename Map  // top level map iterator
    , typename LastMap  // top level map iterator
    , int Index
    , bool Done = std::is_same<Map, LastMap>::value
>
struct apply_recursive_t;

/*! \internal
    fwd
 */
template <
    typename Template
    , typename Types
    , typename Map  // top level map iterator
    , typename LastMap  // top level map iterator
    , typename First
    , typename Last
    , int Index
    , bool Enable = !std::is_same<First, Last>::value
>
struct apply_mapping_recursive_t;

/*! \internal
    run time compare key values + compile time push_back on \a Types
 */
template <
    typename Template
    , typename Types
    , typename Map  // top level map iterator
    , typename LastMap  // top level map iterator
    , typename First
    , typename Last
    , int Index // current argument
    , bool Enable /* = !std::is_same<First, Last>::value */
>
struct apply_mapping_recursive_t
{
    typedef void result_type;
    template <typename TypeIds, typename T>
    inline static void apply(const TypeIds& typeIds, T&& t)
    {   namespace mpl = boost::mpl;
        typedef typename mpl::deref<First>::type key_value_pair;
        typedef typename mpl::first<key_value_pair>::type typeId;   // mpl::int
        if (typeId::value == std::get<Index>(typeIds))
        {
            apply_recursive_t<
                Template
                , typename mpl::push_back<
                    Types
                    , typename mpl::second<key_value_pair>::type
                >::type
                , typename mpl::next<Map>::type
                , LastMap
                , Index + 1
            >::apply(typeIds, std::forward<T>(t));
        }
        else
        {
            apply_mapping_recursive_t<
                Template
                , Types
                , Map
                , LastMap
                , typename mpl::next<First>::type
                , Last
                , Index
            >::apply(typeIds, std::forward<T>(t));
        }
    }
};

/*! \internal
    mapping not found
    \note should never be invoked, but must compile
 */
template <
    typename Template
    , typename Types
    , typename Map  // top level map iterator
    , typename LastMap  // top level map iterator
    , typename First
    , typename Last
    , int Index
>
struct apply_mapping_recursive_t<
    Template
    , Types
    , Map
    , LastMap
    , First
    , Last
    , Index
    , false
>
{
    typedef void result_type;
    template <typename TypeIds, typename T>
    inline static void apply(const TypeIds& /* typeIds */, T&& /* t */)
    {
        BOOST_ASSERT(false);
    }
};

/*! \internal
    push_back on \a Types template types recursively
 */
template <
    typename Template
    , typename Types
    , typename Map  // top level map iterator
    , typename LastMap  // top level map iterator
    , int Index
    , bool Done /* = std::is_same<Map, LastMap>::value */
>
struct apply_recursive_t
{
    typedef void result_type;
    template <typename TypeIds, typename T>
    inline static void apply(const TypeIds& typeIds, T&& t)
    {   namespace mpl = boost::mpl;
        typedef typename mpl::deref<Map>::type Mapping; // [key;type] pair vector
        apply_mapping_recursive_t<
            Template
            , Types
            , Map
            , LastMap
            , typename mpl::begin<Mapping>::type
            , typename mpl::end<Mapping>::type
            , Index
        >::apply(typeIds, std::forward<T>(t));
    }
};

/*! \internal
    done! replace mpl placeholders of \a Template with the now complete \a Types
    and invoke result
 */
template <
    typename Template
    , typename Types
    , typename Map
    , typename LastMap
    , int Index
>
struct apply_recursive_t<
    Template
    , Types
    , Map
    , LastMap
    , Index
    , true
>
{
    typedef void result_type;
    template <typename TypeIds, typename T>
    inline static void apply(const TypeIds& /* typeIds */, T&& t)
    {   namespace mpl = boost::mpl;
        typename mpl::apply<
            mpl::unpack_args<Template>
            , Types
        >::type()(std::forward<T>(t));
    }
};

/*! \internal
    helper functor to be used with invoke_runtime_template()
    \note cool: mpl::apply works with nested placeholders types!
 */
template <typename Template>
struct make_runtime_template_t
{
    typedef void result_type;
    template <typename Base>
    inline void operator()(std::unique_ptr<Base>* base) const
    {
        base->reset(new Template());
    }
};

}   // namespace runtime_template
}   // namespace detail

/*! \brief runtime template parameter selection

    \param Template functor<_, ...> placeholder expression
    \param Maps mpl::vector<mpl::vector<mpl::pair<int, type>, ...>, ...>
    \param Types std::tuple<int, ...> type ids
    \param T functor argument type

    \note all permutations must be compilable (they will be compiled of course)
    \note compile time: O(n!) run time: O(n)

    \sa invoke_runtime_template()
    \author slow
 */
template <
    typename Template
    , typename Map
    , typename Types
    , typename T
>
inline void invoke_runtime_template(const Types& types, T&& t)
{   namespace mpl = boost::mpl;
    BOOST_STATIC_ASSERT(mpl::size<Map>::value == std::tuple_size<Types>::value);
    detail::runtime_template::apply_recursive_t<
        Template
        , mpl::vector<>
        , typename mpl::begin<Map>::type
        , typename mpl::end<Map>::type
        , 0
    >::apply(types, std::forward<T>(t));
}

/*! \sa invoke_runtime_template()
 */
template <
    typename Template
    , typename Map
    , typename Base
    , typename Types
>
inline void make_runtime_template(const Types& types, std::unique_ptr<Base>* base)
{
    invoke_runtime_template<
        detail::runtime_template::make_runtime_template_t<Template>
        , Map
    >(types, base);
}

/*! \overload
 */
template <
    typename Base
    , typename Template
    , typename Map
    , typename Types
>
inline std::unique_ptr<Base> make_runtime_template(const Types& types)
{
    std::unique_ptr<Base> result;

    make_runtime_template<Template, Map>(types, &result);
    return result;
}

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

namespace mpl = boost::mpl;
using mpl::_;

class MyClassInterface {
public:
    virtual ~MyClassInterface() {}
    virtual double foo(double) = 0;
};

template <int P1, int P2, int P3>
class MyClass
: public MyClassInterface {
public:
    double foo(double /*a*/) {
        // complex computation dependent on P1, P2, P3
        std::wcout << typeid(MyClass<P1, P2, P3>).name() << std::endl;
        return 42.0;
    }
    // more methods and fields (dependent on P1, P2, P3)
};

// wrapper for transforming types (mpl::int) to values
template <typename P1, typename P2, typename P3>
struct MyFactory
{
    inline void operator()(std::unique_ptr<MyClassInterface>* result) const
    {
        result->reset(new MyClass<P1::value, P2::value, P3::value>());
    }
};

template <int I>
struct MyConstant
    : boost::mpl::pair<
        boost::mpl::int_<I>
        , boost::mpl::int_<I>
    > {};

std::unique_ptr<MyClassInterface> Factor(const std::tuple<int, int, int>& constants) {
    typedef mpl::vector<
        MyConstant<0>
        , MyConstant<1>
        , MyConstant<2>
        , MyConstant<3>
        // ...
    > MyRange;
    std::unique_ptr<MyClassInterface> result;
    invoke_runtime_template<
        MyFactory<_, _, _>
        , mpl::vector<MyRange, MyRange, MyRange>
    >(constants, &result);
    return result;
}

int main(int /*argc*/, char* /*argv*/[])
{
    typedef std::tuple<int, int, int> Tuple;
    const Tuple Permutations[] =
    {
        std::make_tuple(0,      0,  0)
        , std::make_tuple(0,    0,  1)
        , std::make_tuple(0,    1,  0)
        , std::make_tuple(0,    1,  1)
        , std::make_tuple(1,    0,  0)
        , std::make_tuple(1,    2,  3)
        , std::make_tuple(1,    1,  0)
        , std::make_tuple(1,    1,  1)
        // ...
    };

    boost::for_each(Permutations, [](const Tuple& constants) { Factor(constants)->foo(42.0); });
    return 0;
}
```