# How to make proper return of templated object in C++?

Tags: c++, templates, c++11

In this code `create_matrix` returns `Matrix<int, 2, 3>` type:

```
#include <array>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

template <class T, size_t ROW, size_t COL>
using Matrix = array<array<T, COL>, ROW>;

Matrix<int, 2, 3> create_matrix(int x, int y){
    Matrix<int, 2, 3> arr;
    arr[0][0] = 42;
    return arr;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    auto arr = create_matrix(2,3);
    cout << arr[0][0];
    return 0;
}
```

Is it possible to return `Matrix<int, x, y>` type?

Comment: possible duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2873802/specify-template-parameters-at-runtime

Comment: ultimately template arguments must be deduced at compile time and so you cannot use runtime values to instantiate a template.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the [XY problem.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/157577)

You could hack together a 2D "matrix" with `vector<vector<int>>` but that's sort of re-inveting the wheel in the shape of a hexagon (meaning: miserably poor performance).

I suggest you try a linear algebra library, for example [Armadillo](http://arma.sourceforge.net/) or [Eigen](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/).

Answer (score 3):

The template parameters for std::array must be known at compile time (either literal values, const values, or constexpr values, that are known at compile time)

So in this case it would not be possible to return a Matrix with x and y passed in at run time.

To get that type of functionality you might need to replace std::array with std::vector or some similar dynamic array type of object, and even then you would have to restructure the code not to take the values as template parameters.