# Parameter values in Template (C++): can be specified at runtime?

Tags: c++, templates

I am new to C++ and I have a question.
Let's say I have a class, function definitions and a main so done ( [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/oldtutorial/templates/) the source):

```
// sequence template
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

template <class T, int N>
class mysequence {
    T memblock [N];
  public:
    void setmember (int x, T value);
    T getmember (int x);
};

template <class T, int N>
void mysequence<T,N>::setmember (int x, T value) {
  memblock[x]=value;
}

template <class T, int N>
T mysequence<T,N>::getmember (int x) {
  return memblock[x];
}

int main () {
  mysequence <int,5> myints;
  mysequence <double,5> myfloats;
  myints.setmember (0,100);
  myfloats.setmember (3,3.1416);
  cout << myints.getmember(0) << '\n';
  cout << myfloats.getmember(3) << '\n';
  return 0;
}
```

The question is: in the `template <class T, int N>`, should the value `N` be known at compile time (like in this case)? Or can be specified at runtime?

Comment: It cannot be specified at runtime. Templates only work at compile time. If you need to specify `N` at runtime then you probably should refactor the code so that it accepts `N` as a non-template parameter.

Comment: Templates aside, `T memblock [N];` isn't valid with a runtime N.

Comment: If you are really really *really* desperate to specify values at runtime, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2873802/specify-template-parameters-at-runtime. My recommendation, however: don't do that.

Comment: @hit I agree it is a bad idea, but not so bad as to use a pre C++11 solution!

Comment: A different aside - I wouldn't trust any site using ["oldtutorial"](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/oldtutorial/templates/) in the path name to teach me modern C++. Also, your sequence is called [`std::array`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/array) while the one with a runtime size is [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/vector).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. All template parameters need to be known at compile time (anything else will result in a compiler error).

The reason for this is that technically speaking, `mysequence<int, 1>` and `mysequence<int, 2>` are completely separate types, generated by the compiler. If the compiler has never seen your `N` before, how could it generate the types for you?

The fact that the compiler needs to generate each of those types separately is also what forces you to implement templates [in the header](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/495021/why-can-templates-only-be-implemented-in-the-header-file). Determining parameters at runtime would obviously be even harder to do (you would need to dynamically recompile your code!).

---

Here is what the C++ standard has to say about template parameters (that are not types):

> A template-argument for a non-type template-parameter shall be a *converted constant expression* of the type of the template-parameter

<sup>[[temp.arg.nontype]/2](http://eel.is/c++draft/temp.arg#nontype-2)</sup>

Now what is a *converted constant expression*?

> A converted constant expression of type T is an expression, implicitly converted to type T, where the converted expression is a constant expression
>   [*some restrictions on the conversions that may be applied follow*]

<sup>[[expr.const]/5](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.const#5)</sup>

So really, it's just a *constant expression* with some conversions added. The rules for what exactly is a *constant expression* are somewhat complex ([[expr.const]/2](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.const#2)), but the standard has a simple summary:

> Expressions that satisfy these requirements, assuming that copy elision is performed, are called constant expressions.
>   *[ Note: Constant expressions can be evaluated during translation. — end note ]*

<sup>[[expr.const]/1](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.const#1)</sup>

*Evaluated during translation* is a fancy term for "the compiler can do it while compiling."

---

Therefore, non-type template parameters must be known at compile time (and so do type template parameters, although it is harder to construct a scenario where you would want to set type template parameters at runtime)