# How to dynamically add template parameter

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, c++14

I'm new to C++ and have got stuck with an implementation. So my problem is as below:

I have interface classes, where the only difference in the classes is the no. of parameters one of its function has.

For Example:

```
class foo3()
{
    private:
       function3(a,b,c) {}
};

class foo5()
{
    private:
       function5(a,b,c,d,e) {}
};
```

To generalize these and use them without knowing their inner functionality, I have created a template class
*fooN* and used template specialization, thus based on template parameter(int N) I can choose correct class object and do some processing.

Now I have algorithm where I'm creating an object of *fooN* template

```
class algo {
     public:
         fooN<5> fooObj;
     private:
 }
```

Is it possible to dynamically assign this template parameter(5) at run-time, or is there a work-around?

Currently I'm using CMake to statically set the template parameter.

Comment: did you thought about std::tuple?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve? Why not just create a version of "foo" that takes an arbitrary number of parameters, either by making it a variadic template (NOT a C-style variadic function) or take a std::initializer_list...?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is it possible to dynamically assign this template parameter(5) at run-time

Absolutely not. All template instantiation happens at compile time.

> or is there a work-around?

Maybe.

You can certainly instantiate `fooN` for a bunch of different values, and choose between them at runtime. The simplest way is something like this

```
int algo(int n)
{
  switch(n) {
  case 3: return algoImpl<3>();
  case 5: return algoImpl<5>();
  default: return -1;
  }
}
```

although you obviously need to get your parameters from somewhere. You can reasonably have each `algoImpl<N>` take a (runtime) vector of argument values, convert it into a tuple, and use [`std::apply`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/apply) to invoke your underlying function.

> Currently I'm using CMake

Commiserations.

> ... to statically set the template parameter.

Eww. Storing bits of your type system in a build configuration file feels a bit hairy. What does your build system know about the correct value of N that your code doesn't?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately this is not possible. Template parameters need to be known at compile time

> When the compiler encounters this call to a template function, it
>   uses the template to automatically generate a function replacing each
>   appearance of myType by the type passed as the actual template
>   parameter (int in this case) and then calls it. This process is
>   automatically performed by the compiler and is invisible to the
>   programmer.

[source](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/oldtutorial/templates/)

Meaning all the values the template can be used with need to be known at compile time.

What you can do is [the following](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2873802/specify-template-parameters-at-runtime)

```
MyClassInterface* Factor(int p1, int p2, int p3) {
  if (p1 == 0 && p2 == 0 && p3 == 0)
    return new MyClass<0,0,0>();
  if (p1 == 0 && p2 == 0 && p3 == 1)
    return new MyClass<0,0,1>();
  etc;
}
```

But as you want an arbitrary number `N`, I assume this is not a solution that is feasible for you. You can try to add a preprocessor macro to generate the function for arbitrary values of `N`, but honestly, I wouldn't do that. It will make you executables very large and add a lot of time to your compile time.

You can maybe find a solution that is similar to what you're trying to do with [initializer lists](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/initializer_list). 
This would let you do something like

```
my_type Var = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, ..., N};
```

You can use such a list as the parameter of a function.

Hope that helped you with what you're trying to achieve!