# Can function templates be instantiated based on the result of runtime if else conditions without creating class templates in C++?

Tags: c++, templates

If following is the definition of simple function template:

```
template<typename T>
T compare(T a, T b)
{
   return a>b ? a : b;
}
```

Can it be called with different template parameter based on some user input during runtime, WITHOUT creating class templates, with different `T` values as follows for example:

```
char type;
cout<<"Enter type: ";
cin>>type;

if( type=='i')
{
   int x=compare<int>(3,6);
}
else if( type=='d' )
{
   double z=compare<double>(5.1,7.9);
}
..so on
```

Comment: What's wrong with what you wrote as your example?

Comment: Please use correct terminology: _class template_ and _function template_.

Comment: sorry, made a few typos there but now corrected them!

Comment: Hint: it's in the name -- a function template is like a blueprint for building a function.  Expanding a template into code requires a compiler, and thus is a language feature, not a runtime behavior.

Comment: @paddy so this code is then incorrect?

Comment: You keep asking for validation, and I think you're not understanding what's been said.  Nor are you reading the answer that's already been written.  It says that the correct approach is to do what you're currently doing.  I agree.  Although it isn't really clear from this toy example what end result you want to achieve, nor is it clear what you consider the alternative to be.

Comment: *"WITHOUT creating class templates"* -- how would a class template help?

Comment: All your templates will be instantiated at compile time. You select one of the created functions at runtime later. That means, you have all your template instances in your executable even if you never use them in runtime.

Comment: [OT]: `T` is deducible, so `int x = compare(3,6);`/`double z = compare(5.1, 7.9);` would be enough.

Comment: Thank you all. @Klaus your comment that all instances are created at compile time and chosen at runtime even though some might never be used answers my main doubt.

Comment: @JaMiT I tried to find similar question and they solved the problem based on interfaces in this example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2873802/specify-template-parameters-at-runtime/2876096

Comment: @leopra Wow. That becomes an astounding amount of over-engineering when applied to function templates. When you adapt an answer to a new situation, you should not assume that your approach is well-known (or even reasonable), especially if it seems awkward (or worse) to you. **This is advice for the future,** but I'll use this question as a concrete example. I would take out the *"WITHOUT creating class templates"* qualification, and instead add a paragraph *at the bottom* explaining that you found a similar question (include the link), but that adapting it looked a lot worse than you'd like.)

Comment: @JaMiT Thanks for the pointers. I'll keep those in mind!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. If you want to determine the type at runtime then you need to do what are you doing (the if else)

There are more advanced techniques for more advance uses, like using polymorphism with a table of callables, but in essence they do the same thing, just in a fancier way.

Comment: You mean proceed by creating class templates?

Comment: @leopra no. You can have a template function or you can have simple overloads or functions with different names. That doesn't matter. You still need to do the `if else` or quivalent.

Comment: So the code that I wrote is correct?

Comment: @leopra it compiles, right?

Comment: It compiles. Does this also apply to parameter packs?