# From boiler plate code to template implementation

Tags: c++, templates, c++17, stdtuple

I am implementing a finite state machine where all possible states are stored within a `std::tuple`.

This is a minimum compiling example of the problem I am facing and its godbolt link https://godbolt.org/z/7ToKc3T3W:

```
#include <tuple>
#include <stdio.h>

struct state1 {};
struct state2 {};
struct state3 {};
struct state4 {};

std::tuple<state1, state2, state3, state4> states;

template<size_t Index>
void transit_to()
{
    auto state = std::get<Index>(states);
    //Do some other actions over state....
}

void transit_to(size_t index)
{
    if (index == 0) return transit_to<0>();
    if (index == 1) return transit_to<1>();
    if (index == 2) return transit_to<2>();
    if (index == 3) return transit_to<3>();
}

int main()
{
    for(int i=0; i<=3; ++i)
        transit_to(i);
}
```

In my case, I would like to change the `void transit_to(size_t index)` implementation to some template construction where all the boiler plate code can be simplified in case I add new states during development.

The only constraints are:

1. Use C++17 or below (sorry, no c++20 fancy features please).
2. Do not change interface (do not propose accessing by type or so on things).

Comment: Do you just want to avoid adding another `if (index == 4) return transit_to<4>();` line to `transit_to(std::size_t)`?

Comment: @paolo Yes, that's the point: Avoiding adding a new line everytime a new state is added

Comment: @Pepijn Kramer Yes you are right and real implementation works as you say. This is an isolated minimun example to avoid struggle with much bigger source code, just to show a problem. So please, forget about FSM, it was just a comment to set context to my question

Comment: @hyde Yes, you are right. I would edit it with your suggestion. Thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Specify template parameters at runtime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2873802/specify-template-parameters-at-runtime)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you only want to avoid adding another line like

```
if (index == 4) return transit_to<4>();
```

when you add a new state, e.g. `struct state5`, you may implement `transit_to(std::size_t)` like this:

```
// Helper function: Change state if I == idx.
// Return true, if the state was changed.
template <std::size_t I>
bool transit_if_idx(std::size_t idx) {
    bool ok{false};
    if (idx == I) {
        transit_to<I>();
        ok = true;
    }
    return ok;
}

template <std::size_t... Is>
bool transit_to_impl(std::size_t idx, std::index_sequence<Is...>) {
    return (transit_if_idx<Is>(idx) || ...);
}

void transit_to(std::size_t index) {
    constexpr static auto tupleSize = std::tuple_size_v<decltype(states)>;
    [[maybe_unused]] auto const indexValid =
        transit_to_impl(index, std::make_index_sequence<tupleSize>{});

    assert(indexValid); // Check if index actually referred to a valid state
}
```

Comment: Although not tagged C++17, OP mentioned: _"Use C++17 or below (sorry, no c++20 fancy features please)"_ Should be a quick fix though.

Comment: This compiles in C++17, doesn't it?

Comment: No, but [this version of your  idea does](https://godbolt.org/z/jf9qjK1fq). Very nice solution. +1

Comment: @TedLyngmo Thanks a lot. I've updated my answer. For some reason, I was convinced that lambda templates where available since C++17.

Comment: I hope you don't mind but I used your idea to populate the map in my answer.

Comment: @TedLyngmo I don't: I'm glad it helped you. You just spelled my name wrong (no worries: "paolo" -> "paulo" is a common typo ;) )

Comment: Oups, sorry! I blame my bad eyes (and that my second name is _Paul_) :-)

Comment: @paola Thanks to you both, Paolo and Ted, the solution Paolo offers is really great, and Ted's C++17 conversion has been really helpful to me. So again, great job nd thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I don't see how you could get away from the translation from a runtime value to a specific instance of a function template, but you could make a map to simplify it:

```cpp
#include <unordered_map>

void transit_to(size_t index) {
    static const std::unordered_map<size_t, void (*)()> tmap{
        {0, transit_to<0>},
        {1, transit_to<1>},
        {2, transit_to<2>},
        {3, transit_to<3>},
    };

    if (auto it = tmap.find(index); it != tmap.end()) it->second();
}
```

---

Building on [paolo](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72826957/7582247)'s nice answer, you could avoid having to populate the map manually:

```cpp
#include <unordered_map>

std::tuple<state1, state2, state3, state4> states;

template <size_t Index>
void transit_to() {
    auto state = std::get<Index>(states);
}

template<std::size_t... I>
void populate_map(std::unordered_map<size_t, void(*)()>& m,
                  std::index_sequence<I...>) {
    ((m[I] = transit_to<I>), ...);
};

void transit_to(size_t index) {
    static const auto tmap = []{
        std::unordered_map<size_t, void(*)()> rv;
        populate_map(rv, std::make_index_sequence<
                             std::tuple_size_v<decltype(states)>>{});
        return rv;
    }();

    if (auto it = tmap.find(index); it != tmap.end()) it->second();
}
```

Comment: but then the whole tuple can be removed and the whole map is just a runtime map from index to state which would simplify things even a bit more

Comment: @PepijnKramer Possibly. I assume that once the template "domain" has been entered, there are things OP would prefer to be done during compile time.

Answer (score 1):

I think put pointers to functions in array can make this nice clean and fast. It is even agnostic to fact that there is a `std::tuple`.

```cpp
using States = std::tuple<state1, state2, state3, state4>;

template<typename State>
void transit_to()
{
    std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << '\n';
}

template<typename>
struct state_array;

template<template<typename...> class States, typename...Ts>
struct state_array<States<Ts...>>
{
    static constexpr std::array transitions { &transit_to<Ts>... };
};


void transit_to(size_t index)
{
    state_array<States>::transitions[index]();
}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/Exfn8ben1